# Changing Textcolor and Background of a TextView

Tags: android, colors, fonts, background, selector

I am totaly new in Android development.

I try to change the FontColor and the Background of ListViewItem if it`s selected or pressed.
Changing the Background is absolutely no Problem by using following selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:state_pressed="true"
         android:drawable="@drawable/background_pressed"></item>

   <item android:state_focused="true"
         android:drawable="@drawable/background_pressed"></item>

   <item android:state_selected="true"
         android:drawable="@drawable/background_pressed"></item>

   <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>

</selector>
```

But how can I change the Background and the FontColor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the TextView's font color is done in the same way as the listitem's backgroundcolor: create a StateListDrawable and set the `TextView`'s `android:textColor` to your custom drawable.

For an example, see [Change ListViews text color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167230/710990). Combine this with what you already have for the listitem's background.

If you want the colors to fade into eachother, set (e.g.) `android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"` in the `<selector>`-tag.

Comment: Thank you, thats it.
Thank you also for the special note to fade the Colors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView txtName;
    txtName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) v;
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Minh Binh can u please tell me how can i change textcolor on hover in case of textview while my textview is inside row