# Navigation Drawer Problems

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

in my android project, I have set up a navigation drawer. Now, on swiping, the drawer works fine but I have a few problems that I'd liked solved.

- There is no drawer icon to the left side of my launcher icon in the action bar. How do you implement that. Also when I click on the `action bar` icon, the navigation drawer does not slide in.
- I would like to change the color of the text of my `ListView` inside my navigation drawer. I tried changing `android:textColor` in the `xml` layout but it didn't work.
- I have the `drawer_shadow.9.png` drawable of the navigation drawer and I tried implementing it using the `setDrawerShadow(drawable, gravity);` method but it didn't seem to work. In the two parameters I added the drawable and the `ListView R.id` for the gravity.

That's just about it. Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Download the same and run the example http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html

Comment: thank you. I shall look into it

Comment: why not use a custom listview and set a selector for the textview to change color for your second point

Comment: ok i will try. Do you know a good tutorial for list views?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166099/change-listviews-text-color-on-click. you can search SO there are may post that might interest you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no drawer icon to the left side of my launcher icon in the action bar. How do you implement that. Also when I click on the action bar icon, the navigation drawer does not slide in.

[Use `ActionBarDrawerToggle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html).

> I would like to change the color of the text of my ListView inside my navigation drawer. I tried changing android:textColor in the xml layout but it didn't work.

If the "xml layout" is the one for the row, it should work. If the "xml layout" is the one for the drawer (where your `ListView` is), it should not work.

> In the two parameters I added the drawable and the ListView R.id for the gravity.

From elsewhere in the `DrawerLayout` documentation, I think your interpretation of the second parameter is off:

> Gravity.LEFT to move the left drawer or Gravity.RIGHT for the right. GravityCompat.START or GravityCompat.END may also be used.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, I'd like to know how to change the color of the text in the listview.

Comment: and also the shadow, I have no idea what to put in the second parameter

Comment: @ADeveloper: I answered both of those. Your text color comes from your row defintions, such as a layout file that you are using for the row. Try `Gravity.LEFT` or `Gravity.RIGHT` with `setDrawerShadow()`, depending upon whether your drawer is on the left or on the right.

Comment: I do not have a layout file for my row. I am using simple_list_item_1

Comment: @ADeveloper: "I do not have a layout file for my row. I am using simple_list_item_1" -- then create your own layout file to use for the rows.